# Using Like in sql query with pandas.read_sql while reading table from Microsoft Access Database using pyodbc

Tags: pandas, pyodbc

I am having a Microsoft Access Database table in which Location column has many locations with "NY" as a substring. I want to get all these locations using like keyword in pandas.read_sql().
I am trying the below query.

```
par="TD"

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={};DBQ={}'.format(driver, dbq))

sql='SELECT Name,Designation,Location from UserInfo where Location Like '%s''%par

data=pandas.read_sql(sql,cnxn)
```

I am getting an empty dataframe.
   '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={};DBQ={}'.format(driver, dbq))

data=pandas.read_sql_query("SELECT Name,Designation,Location from UserInfo where Location Like '%TD%' ",cnxn)
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
params=("TD%")

sql="SELECT Name,Designation,Location from UserInfo where Location Like ?"

data=pandas.read_sql(sql, cnxn, params=params)
```